# QlikView: aggregating a calculated expression

Tags: qlikview

I have a table that is used to calculate a daily completion score by individuals at various locations. Example: on day 1, 9/10 people completed the task, so the location score is 90%. The dimension is "ReferenceDate." The expression is a calculation of count(distinct if(taskcompleted=yes, AccountNumber)) / count(distinct AccountNumber).

Now, I want to report on the average scores per month. I DO NOT want to aggregate all the data and then divide; I want the daily average. Example:

day 1: 9/10 = 90%
day 2: 90/100 = 90% (many more people showed up a the same location)
average of two days is 90%.

it's not 99/110
and it also not distinct(99) / distinct(110). It is the more simple (.9 + .9) /2

Does this make sense?

What I have now is a line graph showing the daily trend across many months. I need to roll that up into bar charts by month and then compare multiple locations so we can see what locations are having the lower average completion scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `aggr()` function to tell QlikView to do the sum day by day and then average the answers.

It should look something like this. (I just split the lines to show which terms are working together.

```
avg(
   aggr(
      count(distinct if(taskcompleted=yes, AccountNumber)) 
      / count(distinct AccountNumber)
   ,ReferenceDate)
)
```